# DELL PE 2950/1950 IPMI iso from internet

Tags: http, dell, ipmi, iso

I'm wondering if I could ask my IPMIs to load the OS ISO to boot from an Internet/HTTP URL?

Have anyone already tried such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an iDRAC across the network from your PC and mount an ISO to boot from using a web browser and java.  The iDRAC is an optional component though so you may not have one installed.

So google up on iDRAC for further info.

Comment: Yep I know that you can use an ISO image from my computer using the Idrac but what I'm trying to do is use racadm to mount a virtual CD-ROM which will use an ulinux ISO from a URL like http://images.domain.tld on the net. All my servers already have the Idrac installed and working.

Comment: racadm remoteimage only works with network shares. I'm not sure it is possible or wise to boot entirely from the internet. Your best case is prolly using one of these methods or PXE to mount a small network install iso which will then fetch the rest of the packages from the net.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid indeed. I don't get why (except slowlyness) idrac or ipmi devices couldn't use iso from the web as they're able to use shares and ftp addresses, so it may be a protocol implementation issue or sort of.

Comment: I don't think they would expect anyone to want to.  When you do a net install from a trusted iso you have the keys to check that the rest of the packages you pull have not been modified.  If you booted directly not only might there be latency issues but you have no protection against malicious code.

Comment: Yep, but indeed, it's not so insecure as the tiny image is relaimed from a HTTPS endpoint using authentication and image check exclusively used to load another image.
Indeed, I think that I'll have to deal with racadm and the virtual flash card as a installation source.